# Construct a basis from 2 vector sets

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to construct a basis for R^3 by choosing 2 vectors from one set and 1 vector from another set?

I know that the basis can be constructed if 3 vectors are linear independent but I don't know if you can take from different sets.

Comment: What kind of sets do you mean? Just any old subsets of $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: If you can choose your subsets freely, then you certainly can. That's the basis completion theorem. If the subsets are given, then it depends on the subsets. For instance, the sets $\{(1,0,0),~(0,1,0)\}$ and $\{(1,1,0)\}$ won't allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basis is defined a subset of a given vector space which is linearly independent and spans the entire vector space. You do not need to care about where the elements of the basis came from, as when you construct a basis you are always creating a new set of elements. For example, if we're considering $\mathbb{R}^3$, the standard basis is given by
$$
\alpha  =\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}
$$
You could think of this as taking two vectors from the set $\{(1,0,0),(1,1,1),(0,0,1)\}$ and one vector from the set $\{(2,2,3),(0,1,0)\}$ but it doesnt matter. The important part is that your basis vectors lie in the underlying vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Of course this doesn't mean that given at least three vectors you can construct a basis, it just depends on what the vectors are.